# How to show specific item in question on trigger entry? (Unity & c#)

Tags: unity, c#

So I have multiple, random objects on a plane, and when my player walks into them, I want them to be 'picked up'. The player can only hold one object at a time, and needs to return the item to the base before he can pick up another. Using the OnTriggerEntry function in a collider script, a set of commands are called when the player touches the object. Within the function, the 'itempickup' function from the player script is called using 'col.transform.SendMessage()'. How do I tell the itempickup function which specific object was 'picked up' in the trigger script? That is, is there a variable of some kind that acts as an ID for game objects? Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For very simple and limited(in numbers) you could give each of your items [tag](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Tags.html).
Alternatively, you can take advantage of the `OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)` method signature - the one of the colliding object will be `this`(.gameObject) and the other one is `other.gameObject`. This way you can access attached components directly, including all scripts. So assuming you have something like `Hands` script on player and collider script on the item you could do something like:

```
//on player
public Hands {
  public Item ItemHeld { get; private set; }
  public void EquipItem(Item item) { /*some logic e.g. drop old assign new item*/  }
  public void DropItem() { /*some logic*/}
}

//on item
public Item {
  public string name;
  public OnTriggerEnter(Collider other) {
    if(other.gameObject.tag == "player")//or just assume it is always player
      other.gameObject.GetComponent<Hands>().EquipItem(this);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, also, what is the difference between using 'Collider other' and 'Collision col' in the trigger arguments? I was using 'Collision col' and don't know how your method differs

Comment: @BrandonEdwards none. You can name the argument as you like. It is however best to name it so its semantics is clear from the name - if "col"(=short for collider) clear for you, go for it. It is just about personal preference: `public OnTriggerEnter(Collider <put your favorite name here>)`

Comment: Script error: OnTriggerEnter
This message parameter has to be of type: Collider
The message will be ignored.

Comment: I now get this error ^ and i'm not sure how to fix it?

Comment: @BrandonEdwards It sais exactly what the error is - the *type* should be `Collider`, perhaps you omitted the type and wrote only the name? If this does not help you, post the line where the error it.